# Android Gradle file common names

Tags: android, gradle

I'm working on a tutorial and it references the "project-level build.gradle file", the "app-level build.gradle file" and then mentions the "top-level build.gradle file".

It seems to me that "top-level build.gradle file" and "project-level build.gradle file" are actually the same thing and that "app-level build.gradle file" might also be called the "module level build.gradle file".

Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to me that "top-level build.gradle file" and "project-level build.gradle file" are actually the same thing

Most likely. Personally, I use those terms interchangeably, though I've been trying to use "top-level" more.

> and that "app-level build.gradle file" might also be called the "module level build.gradle file".

Yes, and that's a better term for experienced Android developers, since some projects will have more than one module. However, some developers may not have learned what a module is, or may go looking for a directory named `module`. In a typical Android Studio project, there is a module named `app`, so "app-level `build.gradle` file" is a bit more approachable for newcomers.